# No Coding Required Database Management Tool (CRM?) Equivalent to Microsoft Access

Tags: database, data-visualization, sql, microsoft-access

I'm looking for software where I can manage a database created from excel/Google sheets. Ideally, I'd like to import the documents into the SQL database. I have experience in SQL so set it up, however, my team does not for managing it.

The user should be able to add data to tables, query data, manipulate the data, and all the other standard (nothing too complex like Inner Joins) functions for query data from a DB.

Microsoft Access does this extremely well for PC computers who have no coding skills. However, I need a Mac OS X solution that doesn't require coding skills.

Does anyone know of anything?

I have looked around Software Recommendations as well as online but I couldn't find anything solid.

Would be great if someone could recommend one.

Thank you!

Comment: *Ideally, I'd like to import the documents into the SQL database*. I would drop the **ideally** and **like**. Maintaining a database in spreadsheet quickly turns into nightmares.

Comment: How about [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/)?

Comment: LibreOffice doesn't let me upload Excel/Google Sheet docs. Is there maybe any CRM which does this?

Comment: Have you looked at [FileMaker](http://www.filemaker.com/) or [4D](http://www4D.com)? If so, edit your Question to indicate how they do and do not meet your needs. Neither does SQL, but both are database tools capable of imports and exports.

Comment: No, I haven't! FileMaker is great! Like you said, it's not an SQL tool but it performs exactly what I need. Thank you :)